# DevOps Organisation Not Appears in My Account

Tags: azure-devops

My Account(AAD) is Linked with 2 DevOps Organisation(personal organization & Business orgnaization)

I am unable to view Business orgnaization on DevOps Profile but able view personal organization.
I am able to access both via Url https://dev.azure.com/xxxCloud/.

I can't able to Connect DevOps Business Organisation with Visual Studio also.

Comment: I believe Microsoft has a support contact available for Azure Devops. You should use it

Comment: @Murugenthiran Karthikeyan How about the issue?  Would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. Please enter **aka.ms/vssignout** in browser and login to **aka.ms/vsprofile** again to see if the issue still exists.
2. If your organizations are in different AADs, please select the right directory in the dropdown list.

[image]

3. Please use other PCs to sign in and check if it works.
4. If you sign in this organization, can you see the projects in it? Please click specific projects in Web UI, or add project name in organization URL to get access to it.
5. Please ask your AAD admin to remove your MSA account from Azure Active directory and re-add you again to check if the issue still exists.